# ssh Mac Unix: copy a file with special characters and spaces

Tags: mac, bash, filenames, cp

I am remote logged into a Mac and trying to copy a music file from one directory to another, but I am getting an error. I think it's caused by spaces or special characters, but not sure.

the file is:

```
01 Your Everything (feat. Louisahhh!).m4a
```

I tried a few variations of the following to cp the file (this is just a test to rename):

```
cp 01\ Your\ Everything\ (feat.\ Louisahhh!).m4a dd.m4a
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Ahh, wait adding escape characters to the ! and () characters did the trick.

Comment: brackets should be fine, but it don't like that bang! I was going to suggest using autocomplete (<tab>) to see what the system thinks it's called, but no need now.  Maybe next time

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try tomorrow, but escaping the brackets as well as the bang seemed to work.

Comment: Next time just do `cp "long filename with special characters.m4a" dd.m4a`

Comment: @terdon: double-quotes won't work, since it still interprets history substitutions (`!`) in them -- but single-quotes would do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either to enclose your filename in single quotes `'` or to escape all the special characters.

- In your example spaces, parenthesis and the quotation mark need to be escaped. See [this list](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) or the shell manual page for the list of special characters and their meaning.

  ```
  01\ Your\ Everything\ \(feat.\ Louisahhh\!\).m4a
  ```
- Or you can use single quotes `'` (not double quotes since several characters are still interpreted).

  ```
  '01 Your Everything (feat. Louisahhh!).m4a'
  ```

  Keep in mind that you if you have a single quote in a file you will have to quote it differently. For a file called *It's done*:

  ```
  'It'\''s done'
  ```

Comment: +1. You can simplify the last example *a bit*: `'It'\''s done'`